# How to schedule BigQuery DataTransfer Service using bq command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-bigquery, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a Data Transfer service using BigQuery. I used bq command to create the DTS,

1. I am able to create DTS successfully
2. I need to specify custom time for scheduling using the bq command

Is it possible to schedule custom time while creating the Data Transfer service. Refer sample bq command

```
bq mk --transfer_config \
--project_id='My project' \
--target_dataset='My Dataset' \
--display_name='test_bqdts' \
--params='{"data_path":<data_path>,
"destination_table_name_template":<destination_table_name>,
"file_format":<>,
"ignore_unknown_values":"true",
"access_key_id": "access_key_id",
"secret_access_key": "secret_access_key"
}' \
--data_source=data_source_id
```

> NOTE: When you create an Amazon S3 transfer using the command-line tool, the transfer configuration is set up using the default value for Schedule (every 24 hours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the flag `--schedule` as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query)

> **Option 2: Use the bq mk command.**
>
> Scheduled queries are a kind of transfer. To schedule a query, you can
>   use the BigQuery Data Transfer Service CLI to make a transfer
>   configuration.
>
> Queries must be in StandardSQL dialect to be scheduled.
>
> Enter the bq mk command and supply the transfer creation flag
>   --transfer_config. The following flags are also required:
>
> - --data_source
> - --target_dataset (Optional for DDL/DML queries.)
> - --display_name
> - --params
>
> Optional flags:
>
> - --project_id is your project ID. If --project_id isn't specified, the default project is used.
> - --schedule is how often you want the query to run. If --schedule isn't specified, the default is 'every 24 hours' based on creation
>     time.
> - For DDL/DML queries, you can also supply the --location flag to specify a particular region for processing. If --location isn't
>     specified, the global Google Cloud location is used.
> - --service_account_name is for authenticating your scheduled query with a service account instead of your individual user account. Note:
>     Using service accounts with scheduled queries is in beta.
>     
>     bq mk \ 
>     --transfer_config \
>     --project_id=project_id \
>     --target_dataset=dataset \
>     --display_name=name \
>     --params='parameters' \
>     --data_source=data_source

If you want to set a 24 hours schedule, for example, you should use --`schedule='every 24 hours'`
You can find the complete reference for the time syntax [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref)

I hope it helps

Comment: --schedule is to schedule a query, but I need to schedule the Data Transfer Service which I have created through bq command.

Comment: In the link I sent you can find this piece of information: "Scheduled queries are a kind of transfer. To schedule a query, you can use the BigQuery Data Transfer Service CLI to make a transfer configuration"

This answer I provided you should work

Comment: I am able to schedule using the above mentioned document. Thanks!!

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks!! That _cron.yaml Reference_ I've been searching all over the _freakin_ place. No reference to it in the main _Scheduling queries_ reference whatsoever! Would it have killed them to use just plain `cron`? I feel like `"whenever I feel like it"` is an option 9__9

Comment: what crom.yaml reference